# Modules appear in new DotNetNuke page, but they are not specified in any template file

Tags: templates, dotnetnuke

I inherited a DNN (6.2.5, upgraded several times from 5.6.2) site and every time I add a new page, multiple instances of several modules (i.e. 3 copies of module A, 3 copies of module B, 1 copy of module C, etc.) appear automatically in the page, as if there were a template specifying them. I don't want them and have to delete them all every time I add a new page, which is a pain. Funny thing is, I have looked in all the *.template files and they are not specified in anywhere.

Does anyone have an idea of where to look to find why these modules appear automatically on adding a new page, despite their not being in any template file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that each of them has "Display Module On All Pages" checked in the module settings. When that happens, they are injected implicitly on every page on the site.

Comment: I see that now. Thanks very much. So am I right taking this one step further to assume that the modules that appear multiple times have this option checked in multiple pages? i.e. having it clicked in the settings of Page A make it appear once on the new page and having it clicked in the settings of Page B makes it appear a second time, and so on?

Answer (score 3):

Ian Robinson's comment is the root cause with the display issue.

**BUT**: I wanted to post a separate answer as a warning with  more detail on how it works and a word of caution on making a change

You can find the module then "Uncheck" the "Display Module On ALl Pages" option.  However, on certain versions of DotNetNuke doing this will remove it from all pages that it was automagically added to.  Re-Checking this option will result in the content being added to the COntentPane of all pages, which might be what you want, and could have a major impact on your layout.  SO be careful and I strongly recommend a backup of the site/database in case it goes wrong.

In general, this option is VERY scary to use!

Comment: A very useful observation. Thanks very much. So I guess what I have to do is make note of where all I want this thing appears, where all I want it to appear, unclick the option and then clean it up. Seems like lazy work on the part of the original developer.

Comment: John - Yes, it is complicated.  And personally it is this behavior that I tell my clients to NEVER use this function.  There are better ways with more control.   (I'm actually writing a blog about this now.)

Comment: I strongly agree with you, Mitchel. To fix it, I found which modules were generating the instances in the new page, unclicked the box 'Display Module On All Pages' and then restored the ones I wanted from the recycle bin. Kind of a pain, but now, new pages are as I want them. Thanks again for your help and advice!